# I want to check if I have already stored data, and if not then i want to store it in my mongodb database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

This is the code that I am using, so if i find a document with the same uuid i dont want to save it.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect("mongodb+srv://connection string", {useNewUrlParser: true});
var db = mongoose.connection;
const Meeting = mongoose.model('Meeting',
  {
    host_id: String,
    topic: String,
    type: Number,
    start_time: String,
    duration: Number,
    timezone: String,
    created_at: String,
    join_url: String,
    agenda: String,
  });
        //STEP 4
        //we can now use the access token to make API calls
        request.get('https://api.zoom.us/v2/users/'+email+'/meetings', function (error, response, body) {
          if (error) {
            console.log('Error in API ', error)
          } else {
            body = JSON.parse(body);
            //display response in console
            console.log('API call ', body);       
            //save in db
            for (const m of body.meetings) {
             // m=JSON.parse(m);
              if(db.meeting.countDocuments({'uuid': m.uuid}, { limit: 1 })==0{
                let meeting = new Meeting(m);
                meeting.save();
              }
            }

          }
```

But the error that I am getting is :
TypeError: Cannot read property 'countDocuments' of undefined.

Comment: can you share the whole code regarding this for loop (where you define "body" and its properties) and also share the model Schema

Comment: I have edited my post. Please have a look at it.

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 0):

Very basic request to find a document with a specific uuid, if it doesn't exist, save it.

```
Meeting.findOne({'uuid': uuid}, (err, existingMeeting) => {
    if (err) { 
      /* handle the error
      return / send a response */
    }
    if (existingMeeting) {
      /* handle the existence of this uuid
      return / send a response */
    }
    Meeting.save((err) => {
      if (err) { 
      /* handle the error in saving
      return / send a response */
      }
      /* everything has saved
      return / send a response */
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I do it with express so my solution is:
Just one problem, I don't understand where that `email` come from

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();


 router.get('https://api.zoom.us/v2/users/'+email+'/meetings', (req, res) => 
    {
    const { uuid } = req.body; 


    //check existing meeting
    Meeting.findOne({ uuid}).then(meeting => {
      if (meeting) return res.status(400).json({ meeting: "The Meeting with this Id is already exist" });

    });
});
```